# How to checkout a git repository in Jenkins groovy script

Tags: jenkins-groovy

In my Jenkins job, I am having Active Choices Reactive Parameter

My requirement is to clone a git repository and process one of the from that repository

In Jenkins, I have the credential for that git repository with required privileges

Can someone explain, how to clone the git repository in the Groovy script part of the Active Choices Reactive Parameter ?

Comment: Can you please paste your active choice source code?

Comment: @KarolinaOchlik

Cloning will be the first step in my Active Choices Reactive Parameter's groovy script

Only after cloning  I have to write remaining part of the code

So, I don't have any code to copy paste now

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.